# Minimum of f(x,y,z)

Tags: calculus, inequality

let $x,y,z> -1$,then how can we find the minimum of this function
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1+x^2}{1+y+z^2}+\frac{1+y^2}{1+z+x^2}+\frac{1+z^2}{1+x+y^2}$$
I think that we can use a famous inquality but  I can not find it.

So thanks

Comment: You have to find critical points respect to every variable.If there is a match in some point, at that point the function takes its minimum value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For every $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$t\le\frac{1+t^2}{2}$$
thus
$$\frac{1+x^2}{1+y+z^2}\ge\frac{1+x^2}{1+z^2+\frac{1+y^2}{2}}$$
$$\frac{1+y^2}{1+z+x^2}\ge\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2+\frac{1+z^2}{2}}$$
$$\frac{1+z^2}{1+x+y^2}\ge\frac{1+z^2}{1+y^2+\frac{1+x^2}{2}}$$
Set $a=1+x^2$ , $b=1+y^2$ and $c=1+z^2$, so
$$f(x,y,z)\ge \frac{2a}{2c+b}+\frac{2b}{2a+c}+\frac{2c}{2b+a}$$
By application of Cauchy inequality, we have
$$\left(\frac{2a}{2c+b}+\frac{2b}{2a+c}+\frac{2c}{2b+a}\right)\left[\,a(2c+b)+b(2a+c)+c(2b+a)\,\right]\ge 2(a+b+c)^2$$
thus
$$\left(\frac{2a}{2c+b}+\frac{2b}{2a+c}+\frac{2c}{2b+a}\right)\ge \frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{3ab+3bc+3ac}\ge 2$$
finally
$$\color{red}{f(x,y,z)\ge 2}$$

**Note**

If $u=\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{2c+b}}\ ,\, \sqrt{\frac{b}{2a+c}}\, ,\,\sqrt{\frac{c}{2b+a}}\right)$ and $v=\left(\sqrt{a(2c+b)}\,,\,\sqrt{b(2a+c)}\,,\,\sqrt{c(2b+a)}\,\right)$
then
$$\|u\|^2\,\|v\|^2\ge(u.v)^2$$
and
$$\frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{3ab+3bc+3ac}\ge 2\Leftrightarrow (a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2\ge 0$$

Comment: True, but what values of $x$, $y$, $z$ produce the minimum value $2$?

Comment: @WillSherwood Try $x=y=z=1$

Comment: It is not important. please look at the question.

Comment: After looking more carefully, I don't believe that Cauchy-Schwarz was applied correctly.  We have from $C-S$$$\left(\sum_i x_iy_i\right)^2\le \sum_i x_i^2\sum_i y_i^2$$But that is not what was applied herein.

Comment: You have not squared the sum in the numerator.

Comment: Sorry it was typo

Comment: Please expleain last inequality $2(.)^2/3(.)\ge 2$

Comment: @Dr.MV: Behrouz is wrong that it's not important to find the values at which the minimum occurs. The reason is that one **does not know** that equality is attained in all the inequalities unless one checks the equality case, which will in fact give the location of the minimum.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @ user2182 Please look at the question : Minimum of $f(x,y,z)$, I think that we can use a famous inquality but I can not find it